# echoing max or last greater id in a table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get the maximum id from a table.

If I use `mysqli_insert_id`, then it gives 0 value.Plz help or suggest any other approach to get last/max id from table

```
$pre_id = $_POST['last_id'];
$sql = mysqli_query($db3->connection, "SELECT * FROM chat where  id=>_pre_id");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($db3->connection);
echo $id;
```

Comment: here you have select query so how can you get inserted id?

Comment: What do you want to do with this? Ids should be meaningless, what do you want to do knowing the "max id"?

Comment: @Vamsi how can i get max or last  id from  the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM chat
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that you want ?

```
SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```